# You do not have the rights to perform the requested action. while filling content rating in android play store

Tags: android

I am trying publish my application in android store . All is working fine except content rating . I am clicking on content rating and when I click next I am getting following error :

```
You do not have the rights to perform the requested action
```

so is there any permission issue with my developer account ?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have the right "Manage Production APKs". Find the admin and ask for that right :)

Answer (score 1):

I gave access to user as "Edit store listing, pricing & distribution". Now, I am able to update content rating.